# Tornado - why does static files without StaticFileHandler donot work?

Tags: python, html, css, tornado

I am new to Tornado. I am trying to link a CSS file to the html template. I am using jinja2 with Tornado. But due to some unknown reasons the CSS file is not loading up.

**EDIT**: I have created my custom `render_template` function which is working fine.

Directory structure:

```
app.py
static
    css
        custom.css
templates
    index.html
```

Here is my Request Handler's Class:

```
class Index(RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    path = os.path.join('static/css/', 'custom.css')
    return self.write(render_template('index.html', path = path))
```

and here is my `index.html` template:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{path}}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="header">
         asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div><!--wrapper-->
  </body>

</html>
```

but the browser is returning the `404-NotFound` error for the css file with the correct url, that is `http://localhost/static/css/custom.css`

Comment: How does your directory structure look like?

Comment: i've edited the question with the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a guide on how to link static files in tornado:
http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/running.html#static-files-and-aggressive-file-caching

Important is the 'static_path' setting in your settings dictionary:

```
settings = {
    "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
}
```

Now you should be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks, just one thing, `static_url` won't work in jinja2. Do you know any equivalents to it?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about jinja2.

Comment: you should be able to do static_url just fine. 
 
 
`path = self.static_url( css/'custom.css')`